# Turn on or off Android remotely

Tags: android

I have plenty of android tablets placing in different locations inside a large room. I have a self-develop app running on all the tablets.

I would like to turn on or off them remotely from PC. There are already TCP connections between tablets and PC. Or even just turn off the screen and turn it on again? (like pressing the power button once)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). I imagine you can use `PowerManager#newWakeLock` with `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` to turn the screen on and `PowerManager#goToSleep` to turn the screen off in response to on/off command.

Comment: Thanks for info. But what means by "Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this API." so I cannot use it often? If I use it at least once everyday, the device battery will die very soon?

Comment: @AkariKamigishi  If you request `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` it will turn the device on, including CPU, screen and keyboard. This definitely affect the battery life, but once a day (or even a dozen times a day) should be fine, as long as you don't hold the lock for too long. And there is no way actually to turn the device on without affecting it's battery light anyway :) You can play around with different kind of locks - take a look at `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` - it will only turn on dim light.

Comment: *battery life, not "battery light"